# Authenticate and mount home using ssh and nfs

Tags: ssh, nfs, pam, nss

How would I go about trying to authenticate a user against a particular system and then mounting his tree using NFS.

The user would have his own desktop and when the user goes to work on a separate system, the user should be able to say *username*@*desktopname* and their password, this should authenticate his *username* against *desktopname* PC using ssh and then auto mount his home directory from *desktopname* PC on the current PC.

I know that standard solution would be to go with a LDAP server and centralized NFS based home directories. Can I please get some inputs, as to whether I should be writing custom PAM and NSS plugins or are there existing solutions.

Comment: Like sssd? Probably best to just install FreeIPA and create a domain.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is for a dev setup in the lab. Going with IPA and LDAP needs IT support, which they are unwilling to do :(